# How to submit form without deleting the current GET data?

Tags: php, forms, web-deployment

I have this results filtering page that sometimes I want data to be added to the GET parameters by submitting a form.

I tried puting the data in the **action** attribute but it deleted the url's GET data

```
<form action="jobs.php?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>">
```

I tried sending the data as input hidden but it god decoded so equal signs are now using percentage signs and not getting recognized by php in $_GET.

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>">
```

Is there any other way that works to do this?

Comment: You could accept the params as a post and redirect with a get but the bigger question is, what are you actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: You need to add something like `query=` before `<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>` so that you can retrieve it with `$_GET['query'];`

Comment: Why are you trying to pass the whole query string as one value? I’d say, loop over $_GET, and create a hidden input for every parameter to begin with (assuming your data structure that you need to pass is not getting too complex/nested) ... that way, you can access the values “normally” in the receiving script, and don’t have to start manually decoding a query string ...

Comment: @CBroe It cetainly is the query string used to display the current form. As for your problem, `<input type="hidden" name="querystring" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>" />` You will be able to retrieve it in `$_GET['querystring']`